# Angular 2 array after subscribe has elements but length is 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 2 and I have noticed an unexpected behaviour.

I have a datasource class, which extends DataSource, with two variables:

```
private archives = new BehaviorSubject<MyArchive[]>([]);
public archives$: Observable<MyArchive[]> = this.archives.asObservable();
private filteredArchive: MyArchive[];
```

I update archives this way within the class:

```
this.archives.next(this.filteredArchive);
```

Outside in another class I try to subscribe to the observable but it doesn't work:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.dataSource.archives$.subscribe((archive: Array<MyArchive>) => {

        console.log(archive.length);
        console.log(archive);
        console.log(archive.length);
    }
}
```

In the console log it prints:

```
0
<THE ARCHIVE WITH AN OBJECT INSIDE AS IT SHOULD BE, WITH LENGTH = 1>
0
```

So that I can't iterate on the archive variable because its length is 0. What's going on here?

Comment: For the second `console.log` statement, try: `console.log(archive.toString())` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(archive))`. You may see that the array is empty.

Comment: Not sure why you're redundantly creating `public archives$: Observable<MyArchive[]> = this.archives.asObservable();` when you already have `private archives = new BehaviorSubject<MyArchive[]>([]);`

Comment: Are you sure that `filteredArchive` is not empty?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I tried and yes, the array is empty. It means that when I do console.log(archive), I'm printing the real time value of the object. So that what's the error? I mean I tried to update the observable also after the subscription, when I was sure that the subscribe method was called.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I'm doing this as a pattern. The observable should be only readable so that I declare it public, instead the BehaviourSubject is writable so that is private and only its class is able to update it. I followed this official Angular guide:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Comment: And... any specific reason for this pattern?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera No it's just for coherence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I forgot that this.filteredArchive is updated by an HTTP GET request. I was trying to push data within this.filteredArchive using forEach, but I forgot to call then() when all the data are received.
Hence I was trying to access, using subscribe, a result that was not yet ready.

Thanks everyone for the replies!

Answer (score 2):

the issue this the value is already emitted before you subscribe. Think of observables like tv stream and your data is like a show on this stream if you open the tv after the show ended (subscribe after you pushed the data) you never see the show. if you want your observable to keep the last value you can use the Scan operator like this :

```
export const reducer = () =>

   scan<MyArchive[]>((archive, update) => {
    //update your Archive or simply overwrite the value
    archive = update

    return archive

    }, []);

export class datasource {

   archives$ : Observable<MyArchive[]>;

   archives : Subject<MyArchive[]> = new Subject([]);

   update(newMyArchive: MyArchive[]) {
     this.archives.next(newMyArchive);
    }

   constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

   this.archives$ = this.archives.pipe(
     reducer(),
   //use the shareReplay so all your subscribers get the same values
     shareReplay(1)
     );
  this.archives$.subscribe();
}
```

and you can update the Arcjive useing the update method in the datasource class like:

```
this.update(filteredArchive)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this.actions and this.state variables means.

Comment: However I tried to push the data after the subscription method has been called. The problem still remain

Comment: sorry the state should be archives$ and action should be archives

Comment: @Davide https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-update I did put the code in working stackblitz hoping this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're redundantly creating `archives$` and `archives`. You can do it with just a single BehaviorSubject.

I think you should be doing this:

```
// Create a BehaviorSubject for MyArchive[]
public archives$: BehaviorSubject<MyArchive[]> = new BehaviorSubject<MyArchive[]>([]);
// Create a private filtered Array for MyArchive.
private filteredArchive: MyArchive[];
```

And then,

```
this.archives$.next(this.filteredArchive);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use this statement:

```
console.log(archive);
```

a reference to the `archive` object is shown in the console (see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)). The content of the object can be different when you inspect it in the console (by clicking on the arrow) from what it was when the `console.log` statement was executed.

In order to see what the actual content is at a specific moment, you should output a string representation of the object:

```
console.log(archive.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(archive));
```

You can expermiment with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbgwrf) to see the various console outputs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. At least now I know how to correctly check that the result given by the subscribe method is valid or not.