# TS Object is inconsistent and I don't understand why

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm totally frustrated by what seems to be an inconsistent object.

```
this.chatSub = this.chat$.subscribe(chat => {
                console.log("Chat", chat);
                console.log("Members", chat.members);
                console.log("title", chat.title);
                });
```

The `Chat` output into the console is a perfectly good Chat object which is used in another component with a members list view that shows them properly. It has an array of Members visible. Yet the following line, `chat.members` is undefined.

If I use "Assign to global variable" in the inspector, I can call temp1.members and get an array of members. But in browser, above, it's `undefined`. The subsequent call `chat.title` is successful.

Output of the above.
[image: output of the above]

Why??

Comment: Notice the little blue "i" below the first string "18a74a..."? Hover it. That's your answer.

Comment: So why is the whole object not being loaded at once? How can I get members to load in that loop?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026458/1009922).